# Refer to node into a priority queue (iterator)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm with a [priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/) (since I need to keep track of the closest node to the source node).

The problem is: when exploring a node, it might happen that it is linked to another node not yet discovered in the priority queue (i.e. to an element of the priority queue).

It seems priority queue doesn't support iterators, how can I **refer** to a priority queue element when discovering the node associated with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::priority_queue<T>` neither supports iterators nor an interface to decrease/increase the priority of a node: merely changing an element's priority wouldn't update the data structure. What you'd need is a node-based version of `std::priority_queue<T>`. There are priority queues for that purpose in [Boost](http://www.boost.org).

Although it wouldn't get the complexity quite right, you *can* use `std::priority_queue<T>` for Dijkstra's algorithm: instead of storing nodes you'd store edges from visited nodes to possibly unvisited nodes with the priority being the distance of the target node when using the given edge. When popping an element you'd need to check if the node was visited before. The Complexity would be `O(m log m)` instead of `O(m log n)`, though (`n` being number of nodes and `m` being number of edges).

Comment: Thanks, but why O(n log m)? Can you explain that complexity please?

Comment: The change from `log n` to `log m` is due to the priority queue storing potentially many edges rather than at most all nodes. The factor `n` is actually probably wrong: there are in the order of `m` edges inserted which makes it rather `O(m log m)` instead of `O(m log n)` with a priority caoable changing an element's priority.